# Self accept answer ordering incorrect in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, sorting, self-answer

If you view [Can I make two wireless routers communicate using the wireless?](https://superuser.com/questions/19184/can-i-make-two-wireless-routers-communicate-using-the-wireless/) on the Android app, the accepted answer is "pinned" at the top. But since the accepted answer is from OP, it shouldn't be pinned, [but sorted to follow the score order](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).

<sub>Using v.0.1.59</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great catch! This was a bug with accepted self-answers which are on the same question as an unanswered question with more votes.

The logic was already in the app, the check for it was just failing. This has been fixed and will go out in the 0.1.61 update coming out later tonight.